# Android Studio spelling checker with Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, spell-checking, android-lint

Is there are any possibility to use the Android Studio "Spelling", "Typo" checker with Gradle? It's been a while, but I still cannot find any possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Android lint for that, take a look at `Typos` check [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks). You can run it this way:

```
lint --check Typos myproject
```

You can use it via Gradle wrapper:

```
gradlew lint
```

More information about lint could be found [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html).